# Is there worth in having a community wiki about community history?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I've been thinking about the various issues that communities of SE have faced throughout their existence. These issues obviously change over time as the communities evolves. Do you think it would be worthwhile to document issues faced by a community and how they were resolved?

Obviously, these issues are already documented in every meta but there is no overview *per se* (that I am aware of) for users and moderators come and go.  I'm thinking this could also help communities learn from each others' history and also be helpful for anyone stepping in a new role like having moderator tools or being elected as a mod.

Is there worth in having a community wiki about community history? (in each community)

Following the downvotes and the comments below, here is a bit more detail of what I mean. The idea is not to have "crunchy" details about drama with users but really just keeping in one place issues/hurdles that a community has overcome or are currently battling. For example, it's possible that as the scope of a community has been redefined, new communities have sprung (e.g. software recommandations). Another example may be incentives put in place for users to engage with the review queue. Another example would be creating chatrooms for questions that are too localized (e.g. critique questions in graphic design) In a way, a bit of a "Changes log" but more oriented towards community actions than actual platform mechanisms.

Obviously, all this information is available to anyone willing to scour the Meta of a community. My thoughts are that this is going to become increasingly difficult to keep track as communities survive through time and that it could be useful information.

Comment: Issues like what? Meta dramas that end in someone losing a diamond? Or a story more like how a site created a sandbox to combat low quality questions? The former isn't something that need or should be documented elsewhere. The latter however, specifically what actions and policies different sites have used—and still use—might be valuable.

Comment: The 2nd option, issues like self-promotion, defining scope, keeping members' interest, and such.

Comment: Are you talking about a cumulative FAQ of all the stuff the single metas have figured out?

Comment: @Helmar I added more to my question. I'm hoping this is clearer now.

Answer (score 6):

I think this stuff is generally to be found on site Metas already. Organizing it has some merit: the really valuable discussions and decisions get hard to find eventually, even for the people who participated directly.

Probably better than a rewritten and amalgamated copy, though, is [an FAQ index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/159251). This'll likely still require a fair bit of community work to adjudicate, collate, and polish, but it'll retain more of the consensus and real history of the events that you want to preserve.