# Should we have a tag for significant points in time?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

There are many discussions about the current incidence. For example:

- [Summing up the main issues (The Story So Far)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334399/260800)
- [Disclose the discussion that started the current SE-moderators debate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334214/260800)
- [An Update to our Community and an Apology](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334248/260800)
- [An apology to our community, and next steps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334551/260800)
- [Firing mods and forced relicensing: is Stack Exchange still interested in cooperating with the community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/260800)

Should we have a whole tag for this incidence? In general, if in the future there are more crises and incidences like this, should they have their own tags too? I feel it's fine, as we have specific tags for individual events like [winter-bash](/questions/tagged/winter-bash). And, should we have a [crisis](/questions/tagged/crisis) tag?

---

Related:

- [Is there a good term/phrase to denote the "current events"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337953/260800)
- [How can we improve the inconsistent tagging of the questions relating to the recent uproar and associated issues?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337237/260800)
- [How can I keep track of all the developments surrounding the current controversy?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335319/260800)

Note that these questions are specifically about the conflict 2019, while this question is simply about creating meta tags for significant events.

Comment: The best and most used tag has been  `Code of Conduct`

Comment: We should name them like hurricanes are named. How about [tag:crisis-monica]?

Comment: Perhaps [tag:epic-mistakes]? Or just [tag:company-mistakes].

Comment: @Mari-LouA no that would be "The one with the Monica crisis".

Comment: @Shadow how about [tag:epic-failures]?

Comment: @Ooker too extreme..

Comment: **Definitely not "crisis-Monica".** While she was at the center of this crisis, that was not by her choice. In addition, the issues are far bigger than her - moderation in general, license issues, staff <-> community communication, welcoming, inclusivity, etc. Monica is the most visible single piece of this, but only because she was singled out to be "fired" and not, arguably, that she did anything truly "big" herself. In addition, the lack of inclusion of Monica by name in the official statements so far (AFAIK), would make it extremely inappropriate to tag based on her name.

Comment: What about [tag:code-of-conduct-crisis]?

Comment: Code of Conduct Wars - 2019. It is a time of civil war. The Community Team, striking from their hidden castle, have won their first victory against the moderation team. During the battle, a user stole the mystical Hat of Ages. Now, Princess user32767, custodian of the powerful Hat, must gather and unite the Seven Diamonds of Destiny to restore the Old Be Nice Policy to the Stack Exchange Galaxy.

Comment: @manassehkatz unfortunately, using a single person to name is so natural for our minds. Think about Ponzi scheme, Einstein theory, Obama law, etc. Now, I agree with you that Einstein theory should be acknowledged as relativity theory, because (1) Einstein stood on giant shoulders, and (2) that theory is much more developed today than what Einstein did back then, but ultimately people still link it with Einstein. I think if the tag is made ([tag:coc-crisis-2019] is a good one), it should have a synonym with [tag:monica-crisis]

Comment: crisis-2019 would be good, IMHO. monica-crisis - **no**. The difference is Ponzi was an actual convicted criminal - the worst that Monica *may* have done is conduct inappropriate for a volunteer SE moderator - quite a difference.

Comment: @manassehkatz that is not my point. Einstein and Obama are not convicted criminal, but by your logic the events that they happened to be centers are all wrongly attributed

Comment: But Einstein and Obama are remembered (generally) for the good that they brought to this world associated with their science or presidency. Making Monica's name memorable for a crisis that centered around her would be unfair to someone who's primary stack experience has been as a (by nearly all reports) dedicated volunteer moderator.

Comment: @manassehkatz it's not that I don't understand your point. It's that I base my understanding of psychology and linguistics. It's not even about whether the person is worth memorable, or that they brought good or bad thing to the world, or making her name sticking to an incidence that both she and SE wish it hadn't happened. It's just how our brains work

Comment: And you're right. But we, fellow volunteers of Monica on stack exchange, don't need to encourage it. If it hits big media (which hopefully won't happen if things continue to improve instead of get worse) and they name the crisis after her then we're stuck with it. But not unless that happens.

Comment: Please don't use my name in a tag.  I'm a victim not the cause and labels have a way of sticking long-term.  Also, it's much bigger than me.  It's also bigger than the CoC, so it shouldn't be cast as just a CoC issue -- it's a bunch of things, so maybe crisis-2019 is the best option.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297227/is-there-worth-in-having-a-community-wiki-about-community-history

Comment: @MiFreidgeimSO-stopbeingevil that would be a good counterexample

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The series of events which culminated in the firing of Monica Cellio is so exceptional in the history of Stack Exchange, it makes sense that a special tag is needed in order to keep track of the ever increasing number of related posts.

At the beginning, the tags: [code-of-conduct](/questions/tagged/code-of-conduct) and [moderator](/questions/tagged/moderator) appeared to be sufficient to cover the task, many users were hopeful that management would open a private conversation with Monica, which would lead to her reinstatement.  On October 15th, Shog9♦ reassured the community that a solution was within sight; a new process  was being formulated by the team, [“*that'll give Monica a fair shake*”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335607/223820) that would finally restore her diamonds. But on October 22, the dismissed moderator refused to enter the new reinstatement process, arguing that *[“The process starts from a presumption of guilt”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336236/223820)*.

Seven weeks later, there is no sign of the saga ending,  Monica Cellio appears to have [initiated legal proceedings](https://www.gofundme.com/f/stop-stack-overflow-from-defaming-its-users) against Stack Exchange, and management has refused to respond to her repeated requests for dialogue.  The conflict continues.

Hence my suggestion, [conflict-2019](/questions/tagged/conflict-2019)

***Conflict*** because Meta Stack Exchange has been a battleground; employers and volunteers are in litigation; not all users have seen eye to eye, a significant number of Stack Overflow users have expressed serious reservations about the [relicensing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333615/will-concerns-regarding-the-move-to-cc-by-sa-4-0-elicit-any-further-dialogue-fro?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [audio/fingerprinting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331960/why-is-stack-overflow-trying-to-start-audio) issues. Non-native and native speakers have expressed perplexity and concerns over pronouns such as the *singular they*. Meanwhile the  management continues to observe the fighting behind enemy lines.

Volunteers: LGBTQ+ community and long-standing SE members; disillusioned and frustrated SO users; resigned and reinstated mods; suspended users, and diamond moderators; and last but not least, one defamed person. There has been considerable conflict in the last seven weeks with some valiant attempts at pacification but with little to no success.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/conflict) defines *conflict* as

> **1.0** A serious disagreement or argument, typically a protracted one.
>
> **1.3** A serious incompatibility between two or more opinions, principles, or interests.

The year **2019** is self explanatory but if this conflict should continue into the New Year, the tag can be easily modified to: [conflict-2019-20](/questions/tagged/conflict-2019-20)

I am aware, and sad, that the tag is pessimistic but how do you put a positive spin on what's been happening?

Comment: I would suggest going straight for `[conflict-20xx]`, as the C++ standard does. Or maybe `[schism-20xx]`. What is happening now is really a schism between the community and SE, and even between the community itself, and *conflict* makes me think of something I can solve with a three-way merge.

Comment: given that this answer has 14 upvotes, would this be the consensus?

Comment: @Ooker if you are a visiter of  chat, [ask some users on the Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/) for their opinion. I think 14 upvotes is a little low, considering we have seen posts with 100+ upvotes.  Retagging 270 questions won't be fun either, although it could be done in daily batches of five posts.

Comment: @Ooker  Any news from the Tavern? P.S. I deleted my older comments because I edited the answer.

Comment: I would be wary of assuming there will only be one conflict in 2019

Comment: [this person says "infinity"](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8068711#8068711). People in there don't seem to be interested in this.

Comment: @Ooker "infinity" is a good joke, but not a serious recommendation. I think proposing to retag 280 odd questions is a chore that no one feels in the mood to undertake. Pity because "conflict-2019" represents quite well the current atmosphere, "conflict of opinions", "conflict between users" and "conflict between management and users" etc. it's far less traumatic than "chaos" "crisis" or "war".

Comment: Will add this snippet in the answer at some point: […“there is seemingly no end to the amount of conflict that this situation and the events around it has plunged the community into”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333968/223820) @Snow

Answer (score 9):

From the [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/tagging):

> #### What are tags, and how should I use them?
>
> A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question. Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories.

1. I would argue that the topic of those questions is the [code-of-conduct](/questions/tagged/code-of-conduct) and the way one of the [moderators](/questions/tagged/moderators) has been treated by Stack Exchange. Most (all?) questions have either or both of those tags; if they don't, please add them where appropriate. 'Crisis' is not really the topic of those questions.
2. You can't really be an expert in Stack Exchange crises without having a broad knowledge about the various topics here that would lead to said crises.
3. Filtering on questions about the current event is already possible: just search for the name of the moderator, or [code-of-conduct](/questions/tagged/code-of-conduct) and [limit the creation date](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching). An example query would be [`[code-of-conduct] or [moderation] is:q created:2019-09-27..`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcode-of-conduct%5D+or+%5Bmoderation%5D+is%3Aq+created%3A2019-09-27..).

So I don't think we need a tag for the current crisis, nor do we need a general 'crisis' tag; the latter would be a prime example of a meta-tag:

> meta tags, tags that cannot stand alone as the only tag on a question, are not allowed.

Comment: Having a lot of *experience* with a certain topic does not automatically mean you're an *expert* :)

Comment: So what makes you an expert when if it's not experience? :-\

Comment: So if I understand your answer correctly, point 2 is just for the "crisis" tag. Point 1 and 3 are about the "crisis-monica" tag, and kinda reasonable, but they don't explain why [tag:winter-bash-2018] should exist when there are [tag:winter-bash], or tags about moderator election or community-ad. All of them have year-specific tags beside the general ones

Comment: [tag:winter-bash-2018] isn't really necessary, I agree. Elections and community ads don't have year-specific tags AFAIK.

Comment: Those are from Academia, not Meta I admit. Also, we can argue that "windows-7" is unnecessary in Super User as well.

Comment: You may want to move the search query link to the top of your answer, since it most directly resolves the main issue.

Comment: That idea has some merit, but right now the order matches the quote from the Help Center.

Answer (score 9):

I do agree with all the arguments in the other answers, especially [the one written by Glorfindel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334644/245360).

One argument given is that the tag should not be time-sensitive. There are some tags that are used for a specific point in time, with little relevance later on. [winterbash-yyyy](/questions/tagged/winterbash-yyyy) is the most common one. So there is no specific rule against time-sensitive tags and the grouping of posts by a period of time.

I want to point out one counter-argument for creating that specific tag, and that is the significance of the event (just like the [mso-mse-split](/questions/tagged/mso-mse-split)).

I would love to see a tag (with an appropriate name), that just lists all posts related to the current event. Of course, you can use all sorts of filters to find these posts, but a single tag would benefit greatly in finding these posts.

Yes, you could consider it a meta-tag, but still, it is important meta.

Comment: do you mean you disagree with the answers?

Comment: I mean they have good arguments. I do not entirely disagree with those, but IMHO the significance of the event might justify a little easy on such rules.

Comment: what do you think about the [tag:crisis] tag, as an equivalent with [tag:winter-bash]?

Answer (score 2):

I propose [community-crises](/questions/tagged/community-crises), or perhaps [community-crises-2019-2020](/questions/tagged/community-crises-2019-2020).

This phrase "crises with the community" was used [in this answer by employee Yaakov Ellis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343839/172266) on 2020-02-18.

Answer (score 0):

> Should we have a whole tag for this incidence?

Nope. Tags are for long lasting "things". This incident will *eventually* blow over one way or another.

> And, should we have a crisis tag?

Nope. The main topics of the posts can be covered using existing tags: [welcoming](/questions/tagged/welcoming), [code-of-conduct](/questions/tagged/code-of-conduct), [moderators](/questions/tagged/moderators), [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), and [support](/questions/tagged/support).

Comment: [tag:winter-bash-2017] is not a lasting thing

Comment: @Ooker winter bashes get broken down into years because each year is something different I believe.

Comment: then by the same logic "crisis-monica" is also different to "crisis-bob" as well