# How can I keep track of all the developments surrounding the current controversy?

Tags: discussion, meta

As I'm sure most readers are probably aware of by now, there has been an ongoing controversy for the last couple of weeks surrounding the new Code of Conduct, the removal of a moderator, many moderator resignations, and other assorted related issues.

It seems that there are a couple dozen new Meta questions related to this group of events appearing every day. These questions routinely generate tens of answers and hundreds of comments. I am finding it somewhat difficult to keep track of all the different posts and to keep abreast of the latest developments.

There doesn't seem to be any unique marker linking all of these discussions together. It seems like one just has to scroll through every Meta post to find the relevant ones. Even when you do find them, by the time you finish reading them there are another ten questions/answers that have since been posted.

Keep in mind that many people have limited amounts of time they can spend perusing Meta per day, and many people have stretches of time when they can't visit Meta. If someone only has an hour a day to devote to this, or can only check in a few times a week, it seems impossible to actually be able to read everything, or even to approach that level.

**My question is thus:** Is there any way we can organize things to make it easier for readers to follow what's going on? Perhaps a tag or series of tags? Perhaps a dedicated Meta post that lists all the posts relating to theses events, perhaps also subdivided by more specific topics (e.g. posts about the Code of Conduct, posts about pronouns, posts about moderators, etc.). Or some other way that I have not mentioned? I imagine this would be help readers find all the relevant posts to read, and help readers with limited resources determine which posts to allocate them to.

Would something like this be feasible? Would something like this be desirable?

Comment: Kind of a lame answer (hence the comment), but your best bet is to follow [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper). Updates are added there are significant events happen. If you care about the day-to-day, good luck to you.

Comment: And here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334345/223820 The post keeps track of every question posted across the network (or tries to!)  that is either directly or indirectly correlated with the updated CoC. Ahh, it's included in the answer below. Upvoted!

Comment: One way might be to look at all threads with an absolute score of more than 50 in the last four weeks. Might give some false positives.

Answer (score 24):

The question [Firing mods and forced relicensing: is Stack Exchange still interested in cooperating with the community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper) maintains a quite current list of recent moderator related issues (e.g., ones which have been fired, resigned or reduced activities, plus certain written commentary by them) and a list of links to various official type responses.

This [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334345/562482) to the linked question has been keeping track of a quite current list of related questions, both here in the main meta & in other SE sites, with each section sorted in increasing date order to make it easy to check for any new questions. This answer also marks those which are most generally supported (i.e., with a score of at least 200) and official responses. As for its thoroughness, for example, as I wrote this, it had links to 93 questions on just this site, although some are currently deleted.

On a related note, this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334101/562482) to the same question has links to the official responses, plus links to various external Web pages providing coverage of the current issues here.

I've been checking & reading many of this site's related meta posts quite a bit during the past few weeks, and I haven't seen anything else which provides anything even close to this level of overview & links to the posts & answers about this controversy. However, one question & set of answers which has a generally somewhat higher level view of the recent events is [Summing up the main issues (The Story So Far)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334399/summing-up-the-main-issues-the-story-so-far), with it also including an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334529/562482) with a link to, & copy of, Monica's blog about the timeline of events. Also, read [Update: an agreement with Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340906/update-an-agreement-with-monica-cellio).

As for keeping track of updates to specific questions, in case you weren't aware, you should mark them as favorites. Then your user page's Favorites tab will indicate when & where those questions (and any existing or new answers) are updated.

Comment: That does seem to be along the lines of what I was envisioning.

Comment: I added this very question to the linked questions list.